# Run automated tests against `truffle develop` client?

Tags: truffle, truffle-config

So when I start truffle develop in my MacBook Pro it starts listening on port 9545 (even though I don't have any mention of this port in truffle.js...):

```
$ truffle develop
Truffle Develop started at http://localhost:9545/

Accounts:
(0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
(1) 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
(2) 0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef
(3) 0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544
(4) 0x0d1d4e623d10f9fba5db95830f7d3839406c6af2
(5) 0x2932b7a2355d6fecc4b5c0b6bd44cc31df247a2e
(6) 0x2191ef87e392377ec08e7c08eb105ef5448eced5
(7) 0x0f4f2ac550a1b4e2280d04c21cea7ebd822934b5
(8) 0x6330a553fc93768f612722bb8c2ec78ac90b3bbc
(9) 0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de

Mnemonic: candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat

truffle(develop)>
```

And I can certify this because if I run this in another terminal tab I can see the port open:

```
$ lsof -i TCP | grep 9545
node      61830 andres   12u  IPv6 0x8a6b4ab0cefab415      0t0  TCP *:9545 (LISTEN)
```

However, strangely enough, if I send the process to the background, either by `truffle develop &` or `nohup truffle develop &`, then `lsof` doesn't return any TCP occurrence! Why doesn't truffle develop bind to the TCP port when running on the background?

NOTE: The purpose of running it on the background is so that I can instruct my CI to run it before trying to run my tests via `truffle test --network network_config_for9545`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `truffle develop` launches an instance of [`ganache-cli`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) (previously testrpc).

If you only want to interact with an ethereum client for testing purposes you can launch it directly.

To install (only do this once):

```
$ npm install -g ganache-cli
```

To execute:

```
$ ganache-cli
```